# how to show Favicon using local server in Microsoft Edge(although it is working fine in Google Chrome and IE) ?

Tags: microsoft-edge

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" class="teradata-bootstrap marketing-operations" ng-app="marketingOps">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

            <link  rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

        </head>
        </html>
```

I used  portion in my code its working in chrome but not in Edge.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://yoursite.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: thanks for helping!!  can u please tell where we have to put this favicon.ico file in my code. Pls elaborate.

Comment: in <head> tag like <title>abcd</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://yoursite.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

Comment: image upload on your server can you sahre image link pls?

Comment: i can only give relative path according to my client requirement... I have no option using absolute path... can u help in it?